# How to insert pairs of values into an expression

Tags: function-construction

I want to evaluate `mx - 2 x^2 - 2 mx^2 + 4 x^3` for four pairs of values of `m` and `x`. I can specify m and x and get sixteen answers.
But I only want four answers. What is the neat way to specify m and x?

Answer (score 2):

*Definitions*

```
expr[m_, x_] := m x - 2 x^2 - 2 m x^2 + 4 x^3;

m = {1, 2, 3, 4};
x = {a, b, c, d};
```

*Codes*

- With [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html):

  ```
  Thread[expr[m, x]]
  ```
- With [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

  ```
  MapThread[expr, {m, x}]
  ```
- With [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

  ```
  expr[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{m, x}]
  ```
- With [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) and [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

  ```
  expr @@@ Transpose[{m, x}]
  ```

*Results*

All yield:

```
(* {  a - 4 a^2  + 4 a^3, 
    2 b - 6 b^2  + 4 b^3, 
    3 c - 8 c^2  + 4 c^3, 
    4 d - 10 d^2 + 4 d^3 } 
*)
```

*Comments*

Note that with this particular definition, `expr` behaves as if it was [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), so you can simply do:

```
expr[m, x]
```

which also returns the above.

Comment: Also, `Inner[expr, m, x, List]`, although I typically use `MapThread`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[pair_] := Module[{m = pair[[1]], x = pair[[2]]}, m x - 2 x^2 - 2 m x^2 + 4 x^3]

mxList=RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {4, 2}]
(* {{7, -6}, {-8, 5}, {-4, -3}, {6, 2}} *)

f/@mxList
(* {-1482, 810, -42, -12} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation is to define `expr` as a function of a list:

```
expr[{m_, x_}] := m x - 2 x^2 - 2 m x^2 + 4 x^3;
m = {1, 2, 3, 4};
x = {a, b, c, d};
```

Then calculate the four values using

```
expr /@ Thread@{m, x}
```

or

```
expr /@ Transpose@{m, x}
```

or

```
expr[{m, x}]
```